# tls option is not working in prometheus

Tags: curl, prometheus

Hi I have configured TLS in my broker system.I configured HTTPS port in the broker system.

I configured the tls in prometheus according to the documentation.But I am getting exception EOF error.

I check with the CURL it throws SSL: certificate subject name xxxx does not match target host name

I enabled skip verify.Then also I am getting EOF error.Any help will be appreciated.

This is my config file.

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'VERNEMQ'
scheme: https
static_configs:

  - targets: ['192.168.2.10:8883']
  - targets: ['192.168.2.20:8883']

tls_config:
   server_name: mqttelb.abc.com
   ca_file: /home/jk/Desktop/ssl_certificates/jkapp-keychain.crt
   cert_file: /home/jk/Desktop/ssl_certificates/jkapp-cert.crt
   key_file: /home/jk/Desktop/ssl_certificates/jk.key
   insecure_skip_verify: true
```